# regex \w seems to fail on re2

Tags: c++, regex, re2

In the [re2 header](http://code.google.com/p/re2/source/browse/re2/re2.h) it says

```
// C++ interface to the re2 regular-expression library.
// RE2 supports Perl-style regular expressions (with extensions like
// \d, \w, \s, ...).
```

I notice my pattern failing then notice \w doesn't seem to work. here is my code. Why isn't it working?

```
#include <re2/re2.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    RE2::Arg s, i;
    std::string sz("a or b");
    RE2::Replace(&sz, "\w", "!");
    std::cout << sz << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: What is the prob ? What is your desired output ?

Comment: Try escaping the \ -> \\.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Johnny Mopp mentioned in his comment, you are passing the literal `\w` into the string, when you probably meant to pass in the expression `\w`. Thus, you need to use `\\w` to pass the expression.

In fact, in the [header](http://code.google.com/p/re2/source/browse/re2/re2.h) that you linked yourself, the examples all have `\\w` in the strings.

Comment: Well I feel stupid. I guess thats what happens when I don't do regex in anything but C# (I always write `@"\w"` which is the literal `\w`)

Comment: @acidzombie24, We all have our bad days. :)